# Как собрать приложение с JSF на Tomcat?

Tags: java, maven, jsf

http://javastudy.ru/jsf-2/jsf-hello-world-example-primefaces/

Сделал всё по этому примеру, но при запуске "localhost:8080", выдаёт 404 ошибку.

Обычные html странички выводятся, но jsf нет.

Посмотрел много примеров в интернете, всё делаю правильно, в чем может быть проблема, подскажите, пожалуйста? Ну и совет где можно почитать грамотную информацию тоже подойдёт :)

Comment: Что-то есть в логах? Трейсы или ошибки? Или no-mapped в сообщениях ТС? Порт точно 8080, а не 8084? Вот неплохие статьи http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jsf-2-0-tutorials/

Comment: В примере вроде JSF 2.2, а такое старьё как ManagedBean притянули.  Ну это между прочим. Покажите свой web.xml, faces-config.xml и состав war-архива (с папками, какие файлы в папках)

Comment: `JavaServer Faces The Complete Reference`. В гугле ищется несколько толковых любителей JSF. Главный BalusC. Пара-тройка русских имён, но пишут на аглицком, предатели. Китайцы/индусы типа mkyong - заметки на память - не более. И это в лучшем случае. Лучше обходить их стороной.

Comment: Непонятно включены ли в ваш проект необходимые для сервера компоненты для поддержки JSF. Без этого Tomcat расcчитан на поддержку только JSP.  Попробуйте использовать GlassFish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faces Servlet в приведённом web.xml не обрабатывает `.jsf`, попробуйте вызывать `.xhtml` или изменить servlet-mapping на:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```